# How can i change the table <tr> tag value after sum for each looping?

Tags: php, html, laravel, datatable

I want to return the sum of each row back to the tr tag.

```
<?php $check1 = 0; ?>
    @foreach($results as $r)
        <tr @if($check1 != 0) class="hide" @else class="show" @endif>
            ...............content..........
        </tr>
<?php $check1 += sumTotal ?>
   @endforeach
```

I want to do something like toggle to hide the row which equal to zero value. But first loop the value always wrong for the  tag due to first passed value is 0. How can i update the  tag value after sum? Possible to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There's probably a much better way to do it than using variables in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to achieve is: **To hide the first row having value=0**. This can be easily done by incrementing the value in your loop:

```
<?php $check1 = 0; ?>
@foreach($results as $r)
    <tr class="{{ ($check1 == 0) ? 'hide' : 'show' }}">
        ...............content..........
    </tr>
    <?php $check1 += sumTotal ?>
@endforeach
```

one more thing, you are mistaking is that you put hide with ($check1 != 0) i.e. if value is not zero then hide else show!!!